# Using jsoup to login to espn fantasy football league and scrape stats

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I have a pet project i'm working on having to do with espn fantasy football. Anywho my league is private and it requires that I login to the site before I can navigate to the page. For instance on the browser when I go to

http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/standings?leagueId=491518&seasonId=2014

I get redirected to a login page. I'm trying to use jsoup to login and scrape some data off the webpage but I can't get past the login issue. No matter what I try i keep getting redirected.

I inspected the POST and GET requests and found some parameters in the form data in addition to username and password like "submit", "multipleDomains", "cookieDomain", etc. I'm not sure if I need to set those or not, I tried but it didn't either way or I did something wrong. While inspecting I found the login address to be

https://r.espn.go.com/espn/memberservices/pc/login

So when I use that address i don't get redirected but it does not return any cookies that I can use in subsequent requests to bypass the redirection.

I'm looking for some guidance or to see if anyone has had success doing this? I've seen all the "jsoup login examples" and tried several of them but none seem to work. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Maybe there's a better way/tool other than jsoup? I'm not hard set on jsoup it just seems to be pretty popular and stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps someone out as well but it turned out that I did miss one of the items in the Form Data :/ In case anyone is trying something similar with ESPN the proper form data elements are

```
failedAttempts
SUBMIT
failedLocation
aff_code
appRedirect
cookieDomain
multipleDomain
username
password
submit
```

All these can be found using Chrome's developer options and inspecting the login headers.